# What will the equation of a sine wave having the axis as a parabola $y= ax^2$ be?

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry, plane-curves

[image]
[approximate representation of my curve(in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvtXG.png)

Comment: not necessarily what you're looking for, but $ \frac{2}{7} x \left( x - \sin ( -10x) \right) $ looks similar, albeit not a transformation of axis.

Comment: Quite a weird one: just to start the arclenght on your parabola is $$s(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x(1+4x^2)}+\frac{\textrm{arcsinh}(2x)}{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$
Define a point on the parabola through a parametric equation

$$
\vect{x}(t) = {t \choose at^2}
$$

The tangent vector to the parabola is

$$
\vect{v}(t) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vect{x}(t) = {1 \choose 2at}
$$

and a perpendicular vector can be constructed from this

$$
\vect{u}(t) = {2at \choose -1}
$$

moreover, a unitary vector perpendicular to the parabola is

$$
\hat{\vect{u}}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 4a^2 t^2}} {2at \choose -1}
$$

The point on a sine function defined over the parabola can be thus obtained as

$$
\vect{x}'(t) = \vect{x}(t) + \frac{\color{red}{A\cos B \sigma(t)}}{\sqrt{1 + 4a^2 t^2}} {2at \choose -1}
$$

Below there's an example for $A = 0.2$, $B = 6$ and $a = 1$

[image]

In this last expression you could use $\sigma(t) = t$ or $\sigma(t) = s(t)$, where $s(t)$ is the arg-length along the parabola (following `N74`'s suggestion)

$$
s(t) = \int_0^t{\rm d}t~ |\vect{v}(t)| = \frac{t}{2}\sqrt{1 + 4a^2t^2} + \frac{1}{4a}\sinh^{-1}(2at)
$$

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Your expression doesn't reflect the arc length of the parabola. If it needs not to be respected it is enough to use $y=x^2+\sin x$

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the arc length function of the parabola is not invertible in closed form.

Comment: @Chappers why invert it? Just parameterize everything with $t=x_0$: take an $x_0$ value, find the corresponding $y_0=x_0^2$ the corresponding point on the parabola and $s(x_0)$ the corresponding arc length of the parabola.

Comment: Ok, I need it to perfectly reach a minima at vertex of parabola. Also can you express it as simple equation? Without resorting to matrices

Comment: @PradyotSamartha if you want a minima you want to draw $-\cos x$ on the parabola.

Comment: Yeah, i am bad at math, But I want to make a physical model of spacetime warping, which is also inherently wavy.. So I need my planet/body to kinda sit in the parabola, and also touch the wave.

Comment: @PradyotSamartha I see, I have to go offline now, but will come back later

Comment: @N74 If you want the sine wave to have arches of approximately the same length, rather than stretch as the length encompassed by an interval of the parameter increases, you have to use arc length for the parabola, but the original parameter for the wavey part. Compare https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkdhy.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekmvm.png .

Comment: @PradyotSamartha I think it should work now

Comment: @N74 Thanks for point this out, I already took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you have drawn is not a function as it fails the vertical line test.  I know it is just a sketch but the problem is real if you try to bend the base line of the sine wave to trace the parabola.  It is easy to write $y=x^2+100 \sin x$ and get the below.  I picked the factor $100$ to make the sine waves visible.  This doesn't capture the fact that you want the amplitude of the sine wave to be perpendicular to the parabola.  If you don't mind failing the vertical line test, you can write the parabola as $y=x^2, y'=2x$ and note the arc length to a point $x$ is $s=\int_0^t\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx=\frac 14(2x\sqrt{1+4x^2}-\sinh^{-1}(2x))$.  Now you can take the sine of this and add a vector perpendicular to the parabola of length the sine wave you want.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, i am bad at math, But I want to make a physical model of spacetime warping, which is also inherently wavy.. So I need my planet/body to kinda sit in the parabola, and also touch the wave. Could you also simplify/elaborate the derivation, and tell what factors change what in the wave/parabola?

Answer (score 1):

If we apply a transformation which maps the $x-$ axis on to the parabola by rotating points of similar distance from the origin, we get a fairly even sinuisoidal wave about the parabola.

The parametric equation is:

$$\left(t+\frac{at\cos \big(mt\sqrt{1+a^2t^2}\big)}{\sqrt{1+a^2t^2}},at^2-\frac{\cos\big(mt\sqrt{1+a^2t^2}\big)}{\sqrt{1+a^2t^2}}\right)$$
where $m$ controls the sinusoidal frequency.

See desmos implementation [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z026lhxtmc).

[image]